# Ruby 1.8.7 on Plesk 9.5.4

Tags: redhat, ruby, rpm, rubygems

I'm trying to get Ruby 1.8.7 installed on Plesk 9.5.4. I'm currently running 1.8.6 but `gem` requires a newer version of Ruby to be installed:

```
/opt/ruby/bin/gem update --system
Updating RubyGems
Updating rubygems-update
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    rubygems-update requires Ruby version >= 1.8.7
```

An the application I am trying to install requires `i18n` but that cannot be installed because `gem` is not up to date:

```
/opt/ruby/bin/gem install -v=0.4.2 i18n
ERROR:  Error installing i18n:
        i18n requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux ES release 4 (Nahant Update 6)
Kernel: 2.6.9-67.EL (old, I know..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the binary version of Ruby, get the source and install with: `./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install`. After that, you also can get the RubyGems source code and install with `/usr/local/bin/ruby setup.rb`.

Comment: Do I need to remove the binary version or can I build from source over the top?

Comment: You don't. You can backup the binary version `mv /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby.bak` and create a symlink `ln -s /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby`. Try this and let me know if it works.

Comment: It seems that your older version (1.8.6) was also compiled from source (with `--prefix=/opt/ruby`). Take a look at [RVM](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/). It allows you to install several different versions of Ruby on one computer.